# YII2 SMTP email Expected response code 354 but got code "554"

Tags: php, yii2

Друзья помогите побороть ошибку при отправке email , обычная форма обратной связи

```
return \Yii::$app
        ->mailer
        ->compose(
            ['html' => 'feedback-html'],
            [
                'msg' => $this->msg,

            ]
        )

        ->setFrom($this->email)
        ->setTo(\Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'])
        ->setSubject('Тема ..')
        ->send();
}
```

в настройках SMTP указана почта с настроек Yii::$app->params['supportEmail']
при отправке выбивает ошибку :

```
: Expected response code 354 but got code "554", with message "554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients
```

если в поле setFrom ставлю почту Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] все работает нормально , но мне нужно получать письма от имени отправителя $this->email
подскажите где ошибка или как исправить ?